# Concatenate columns value from different table having no relation

Tags: sql

I have two tables Table A and Table B.

**Table A**:

```
   File#    TaxCode TaxProperty Otherdetails
    1       1107    AXXXA        ABC
    2       2013    AXXXB        XYZ
    3       1107    AXXXA        PQR
```

**Table B**:

```
   Tax Code Desc
    1107    Description of 1107
    2013    Description of 2013
```

Desired Result:

```
   File#    TaxCode TaxProperty TaxDescription              Otherdetails
    1       1107    AXXXA       1107, Description of 1107   ABC
    2       2013    AXXXB       2013, Description of 2013   XYZ
    3       1107    AXXXA       1107, Description of 1107   PQR
```

Please help how to concatenate two columns value of different table.

Comment: Which databasesystem you use?

Comment: @Jens I'm not sure it makes much of a difference as most RDBMS implement the `JOIN` operator, which is obviously required in this case.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu The join is cleas but the concatination of strings is different.

Comment: @Jens You are right, I missed that. Thanks for having an eye for detail.

Comment: Still, for a complete and correct answer you will need to tell us what kind of SQL system you're using: SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `JOIN` in order to return the results in the form you want.

```
SELECT
    A.File#,
    A.TaxCode,
    A.TaxProperty,
    B.TaxDescription,
    A.OtherDetails
FROM TableA A
    INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.TaxCode = B.TaxCode
```

The `INNER JOIN` will return rows which have corresponding rows in both `TableA` and `TableB` based on the same `TaxCode`.

In case you don't have corresponding rows in the two tables based on TaxCode but still want all records from TableA to be shown, you might want to replace the `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`, but that's up to you.